# Custom allocator including placement new case

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, allocation

I'm trying to implement a custom allocator for C++ that works on any form of new/delete/malloc/free.
 
How my program works, I allocate at the start of the program a memory pool of x bytes and work with them. For example, when someone writes `int* a= new int;` my program will return the address from the memory pool which is available and marks it as allocated and that address along with the size allocated is removed from the memory pool. When someone writes `delete a;` the address is returned to the memory pool and can be used again.
 **My problem is that I don't fully understand how `new(placement)` works and how should I deal with it**, because when my function gets called to allocate memory on new/malloc I have as a parameter only the size of the memory the program needs and I just return an available address to that memory to be used. Consider the following example

```
auto p = (std::string*)malloc(5 * sizeof(std::string));
void * placement = p;
new(placement) std::string(4, (char)('a'));
std::cout<< *p;
```

On the first line my custom allocated will return to p an address from my memory pool where there is memory available of a total of `5* sizeof(std::string))`, on the third line my custom allocator will allocate again memory returning another address. When I print `*p` it prints exactly what I was expected `aaaa`. 
**Is this how it should work?**

Comment: Placement-new doesn't allocate anything. It just calls the constructor on the storage you passed to it.

Comment: In the example, on the third line, my function to allocate memory is called but the problem is that when my function is called, it is called only with the size it needs to allocate it doesn't have any other parameters. This is the declaration ```void * __cdecl CustomAllocator_Malloc(size_t aSize,  int aBlockUse, char const * aFileName, int aLineNumber);```

Comment: How do you register (?) your allocator? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: The result of placement `new` should be assigned. [**Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c59deab6139a823). This necessity might be unexpected but otherwise you might introduce undefined behavior. [SO: Is it OK to discard placement new return value when initializing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49569305/7478597)

Comment: Btw. Are you aware that `std::string` is just a container (with capacity, size, and a pointer to data) which allocates storage for the actual text bytes internally as well?

Comment: HolyBlackCat my program is https://github.com/FirescuOvidiu/Memory-management/tree/master/CustomAllocator. Scheff, I'm sorry I don't really follow what you want to say?

Comment: `'a'` is already of type `char`, no need to use a cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A normal `new` does two things:

- allocate storage; and
- construct an object.

Now we want to separate these two steps.  Allocating raw storage is easy, but there is no "native" way to construct an object at a given address in C++.  Therefore, the `new` operator is overloaded to serve this purpose, by returning the given pointer for the first step.

We don't need a corresponding `delete`, because we can call the destructor manually.  In C++17, `std::destroy_at` was added to the standard library.  Since C++20, `std::construct_at` can be used to construct an object instead of placement new:

```
std::construct_at(p, 4, 'a');
```

The [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) explains placement new very well:

## What is “placement new” and why would I use it?

> There are many uses of placement new. The simplest use is to place an
>   object at a particular location in memory. This is done by supplying
>   the place as a pointer parameter to the new part of a new expression:
>
> ```
> #include <new>        // Must #include this to use "placement new"
> #include "Fred.h"     // Declaration of class Fred
> void someCode()
> {
>   char memory[sizeof(Fred)];     // Line #1
>   void* place = memory;          // Line #2
>   Fred* f = new(place) Fred();   // Line #3 (see "DANGER" below)
>   // The pointers f and place will be equal
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Line #1 creates an array of `sizeof(Fred)` bytes of memory, which is
>   big enough to hold a `Fred` object. Line #2 creates a pointer `place`
>   that points to the first byte of this memory (experienced C
>   programmers will note that this step was unnecessary; it’s there only
>   to make the code more obvious). Line #3 essentially just calls the
>   constructor `Fred::Fred()`. The `this` pointer in the `Fred`
>   constructor will be equal to `place`. The returned pointer `f` will
>   therefore be equal to `place`.
>
> *ADVICE:* Don’t use this “placement new” syntax unless you have to. Use it only when you really care that an object is placed at a
>   particular location in memory. For example, when your hardware has a
>   memory-mapped I/O timer device, and you want to place a `Clock` object
>   at that memory location.
>
> *DANGER:* You are taking sole responsibility that the pointer you pass to the “placement new” operator points to a region of memory that is
>   big enough and is properly aligned for the object type that you’re
>   creating. Neither the compiler nor the run-time system make any
>   attempt to check whether you did this right. If your `Fred` class
>   needs to be aligned on a 4 byte boundary but you supplied a location
>   that isn’t properly aligned, you can have a serious disaster on your
>   hands (if you don’t know what “alignment” means, *please* don’t use
>   the placement new syntax). You have been warned.
>
> You are also solely responsible for destructing the placed object.
>   This is done by explicitly calling the destructor:
>
> ```
> void someCode()
> {
>   char memory[sizeof(Fred)];
>   void* p = memory;
>   Fred* f = new(p) Fred();
>   // ...
>   f->~Fred();   // Explicitly call the destructor for the placed object
> }
> ```
>
> This is about the only time you ever explicitly call a destructor.

Comment: This is a very well written explanation, thanks now I understand, not planning on using it I just wanted to know how it works. Also, I understand why the custom allocator is called on this line ```new(placement) std::string(4, (char)('a'));``` and what @Scheff wanted to point out.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu The placement new just calls the constructor of `std::string`, which uses `std::allocator` internally, so it doesn’t call any custom allocator.  You can supply your allocator as a template argument to `std::basic_string`, but that has nothing to do with the placement new itself (declaring a variable, for example, also does)

Comment: yes I understood that placement new has nothing to do with memory allocation, my custom allocator isn't called because of the placement new but because of ```std::string(4, (char)('a')); ```. Thanks