# What is happening when I call a destructor from a placement new inside an std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

If I have the following

```
#include <vector>

class C
{
public:
    C()
    :
        m_d(new int)
    {
        *m_d = 2;
    }

    ~C()
    {
        delete m_d;
    }

    int* m_d;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> data;

    data.resize(sizeof(C));

    C* newC = new(&data[0]) C;

    C* cAgain = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&data[0]);
    cAgain->~C();

    return 0;
}
```

What exactly happens? When the `std::vector<char>` is destroyed, has it freed the memory twice? If it hasn't, why hasn't it? If it has, how would you prevent it?

Comment: C doesn't restpect rule of 3/5/0 (fortunately, no copy occurs). Your placement new might have alignment issue. I think [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) is needed for `cAgain`. Except that it should be OK.

Comment: @Jarod42 The default allocator is aligned to `std::max_align_t`

Comment: @Jared42 can you explain the need for `std::launder`?

Comment: @NeomerArcana: See [is-it-ok-to-discard-placement-new-return-value-when-initializing-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568858/is-it-ok-to-discard-placement-new-return-value-when-initializing-objects).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<char> data;` handles its own memory which contains `char`, unrelated to `C`.

`C* newC = new(&data[0]) C;` call constructor of `C`, (which allocates).

When `newC` leaves scope, destructor of `C` is NOT called. (`newC` is just a pointer, not a `C`)

`cAgain->~C();` call destructor of `C` (good). As for `newC`, when scope ends, no (extra) destructor of `C` is called.

So assuming <strike>correct alignment, and</strike> aliasing between `newC` and `cAgain` correct, your code is OK without leaks.

Comment: is there any reason I shouldn't assume aliasing  between `newC` and `cAgain` in the above?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared data as vector of char so the vector object works on data type of char not you class C so when it is destroyed no destructor will be called because char has no one.

so only one destructor is called ~C()